# Minimum mean square in three dimension

Tags: matlab

I have two matrix, `X` and `Y`, both of them are of dimensions `(4,24,16)` correspondent to indices `(i,j,z)`, I need to get the minimal mean square between then and it's index with reference to `j`. I means I will need to compare every vector and get the minimal difference in the vector `j`. I mean I should get the index between 1 and 24. here are example matrix,

```
clear all; clc; clear; 
X = randn(4,24,16); 
Y = randn(4,24,16);
```

but then I stuck how to do the minimum mean square with respect to second dimension j !

please any help ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Execute mean on  third and first dimension, thus resulting in second dimension that you can find the minimum value on:

```
MSE2=mean(mean( (X-Y).^2 ,3),1)
[mmse, argmmse]=min(MSE2);
```